# Replacing icon with image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this template: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/ and am trying to replace the icon, which uses the i tag, with my own logo. I can't seem to find out how to use the i tag with my own image. I tried replacing it with an img tag, but the styling gets messed up. This is the line of html that is causing the issue:

```
<a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
<i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i> <span  class="light">Start</span>  Bootstrap
            </a>
```

I don't know what css, if any, to include since there is a lot relating to the specific class. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you want to change it to another fontawesome icon, just change the `content` value, e.g: `.fa-play-circle:before {
    content: "\f144"; /* change this */
}` Or, if you want a custom image; `.fa-play-circle:before {
    content: ""; background-image: url(/path/to/image/file.jpg);
}`, then just adjust styles accordingly, you'll need to add a few more for it to display as intended. Either way, it seems that custom styling will be required to make necessary adjustments.

Comment: I know this is a dumb question, but do I keep the content the same as before?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you want to replace the icon, then you just need to replace the value, but if you want to display a custom image from the/a server then you should remove the `content` value, and leave it empty, e.g: `content: "";`. You'll still need it there in order for the `pseudo element` to remain displaying.

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work. Am I supposed to remove all text from where it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: UncaughtTypeError's comment is the way to go.

That is because the .fa-play-circle CSS class is affecting the "play icon" using the following CSS (found in font-awesome.min.css):

```
.fa-play-circle:before {
    content: "\f144";
}
```

So, it isn't really an image as much as it is a glyph loaded before the  tag.